# php pdo: prepare() does not execute but query() does [foreach loop]

Tags: php, pdo, bind, prepared-statement

I'm not sure if the issue is with the `prepare()` statement itself or with the `bindValue`s, but I cannot figure out why this works as a `query()` and not as a prepared statement.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
$dbh->beginTransaction();

$record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET :column = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");

foreach ( $qaPairs as $pair ) {
    list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);

    echo "$key : $question $answer";
    $record_data->bindValue(':column', $question);
    $record_data->bindValue(':value', $answer);
    $record_data->bindValue(':key', $key);
    $record_data->execute();
}
$dbh->commit();
```

If I replace the `$record_data->bindValue…`s and the `$record_data->execute()` with

```
$dbh->query("UPDATE `$db`.`$dbt` SET `$question`='$answer' WHERE `key`='$key';");
```

it works.

For troubleshooting, I added the echo statement, and the values printed are just letters and digits and no quoting; also, the database and table names are not quoted/tick'd.

I read in another question that looping causes problems with `prepare` and `bind_`. I switched from `bindParam` to `bindValue`, but that didn't seem to help…

**EDIT**: results of `var_dump($key,$question,$answer)`:
`string(17) "m3dc78db1e8368428" string(3) "age" string(2) "23" age 23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind a table field name. As much as you cannot bind a table name. You'll have to use this code instead:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
$dbh->beginTransaction();

foreach ( $qaPairs as $pair ) {
    list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);
    // Initialize $column here… remember to sanitize it!!!
    $record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET $question = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");
    echo "$key : $question $answer";
    $record_data->bindValue(':value', $answer);
    $record_data->bindValue(':key', $key);
    $record_data->execute();
}
$dbh->commit();
```

Reference:

- [Comment on PHP pdo.prepare.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#71127)

Comment: @jacob, quoting what the comment author said "A very annoying discovery". Hopefully I've discovered the same thing a year ago and it was really annoying, I remembered it took about 3 hours to get what was wrong in my code: nothing.

Comment: @Shredder, thanks for the edit. I'm really mentally sleeping right now: I knew there was something that was wrong in it but I was too lazy to actually fix it so I just added some comments. :)

Comment: Hi Charliepiga, ugh that is so frustrating. I tried switching `:column` to `$question` in the prepare, but then I get a `variable undefined` error for `$question` :/

Comment: There's something wrong in your script then here: `list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);`. `var_dump()` `$pair`, `$question`, and `$answer`.

Comment: Oh, yes, moved the prepare inside the `foreach` and the error disappeared, but the data still isn't getting added

Comment: @jacob, Try to run the query on phpmyadmin first and see if there are some MYSQL error.

Comment: @Charliepiga : I ran it as `query(…)` earlier and it worked (I tried in MySQL Workbench, and got no errors).

Comment: @Charliepiga : I added the result from var_dump at the bottom of my question above.

Comment: @jacob, try to put a `try {` at the top of that code and a `} catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` at the bottom. And tell me what the output is.

Comment: @Charliepiga : Very frustrating: I dunno what happened, but it just started working when I added `error_reportin(-1);`. PS the output of the catch was nothing.

Comment: @Charliepiga, btw thanks for your!! i wish i knew what fixed it, but the `$question` instead of `:column` definitely helped!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5104/discussion-between-charliepiga-and-jacob)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the error mode to 'exception' and used try/catch to display possible errors?
Here is how you do it:

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET :column = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");
        foreach ( $qaPairs as $pair ) {
            list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);

            echo "$key : $question $answer";
            $record_data->bindParam(':column', $question);
            $record_data->bindParam(':value', $answer);
            $record_data->bindParam(':key', $key);
            $record_data->execute();
        }
        $dbh->commit();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
?>
```

I hope this step provides you with more insight.
Furthermore you need to use `bindParam()`, because the values of the variables are changing on each iteration.

Comment: It will still get the error. You can NOT bind a table field name.

Comment: Hi Benedikt, thanks, I did try using the try/catch, but it returns nothing :/

Comment: Well, my answer was not really meant to be an end solution. I'm glad it helped (bindParam).

Comment: @BenediktOlek, commits are useful for not end solutions.

Answer (score 0):

final code:

```
error_reporting(-1);

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
$dbh->beginTransaction();

foreach ( $qaPairs as $pair ) {
    list($question , $answer) = explode('=', $pair);
    //var_dump($key,$question,$answer);

    try {
    $record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$dbt SET $question = :value WHERE `key` = :key;");
    //$record_data->bindParam(':column', $question);
    $record_data->bindParam(':value', $answer);
    $record_data->bindParam(':key', $key);
    //$dbh->query("UPDATE `$db`.`$dbt` SET `$question`='$answer' WHERE `key`='$key';");
    //$record_data->execute(array(1=>$question,2=>$answer,3=>$key));
    //$record_data->execute(array(':column'=>$question,':value'=>$answer,':key'=>$key));
    $record_data->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```